# Conditional averages (AVERAGEIF) in PowerQuery (M)

Tags: powerquery, m

I have this table:

```
Month     Group     Value
  1         A        100
  2         A        115
  3         A        125
  1         B        200
  2         B        215
  3         B        225
```

I am trying to create a new (fourth) column which contains the quarterly averages, hence does something similar to AVERAGEIF exist in Power Query? The result should look like this:

```
Month     Group     Value     Average
  1         A        100       113.3
  2         A        115       113.3
  3         A        125       113.3
  1         B        200       213.3
  2         B        215       213.3
  3         B        225       213.3
```

Apologies for not providing a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code below; no merge necessary. Alexis Olson method will work best for large data sets

```
let Source= #table({"Month", "Group","Value"}, {{1,"A",100},{2,"A",115},{3,"A",125},{1,"B",200},{2,"B",215},{3,"B",225}}),
AvgAmount = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Average", (i) => List.Average(Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Group] = i[Group])[Value]), type number)
in AvgAmount
```

[image]

Comment: no way it does work that way.. I'm getting errors all along, saying my [Value] column doesn't exist, although it's clearly there.

Comment: The code works.  I've edited example code so that it is now a self-contained example. I don't know what your code looks like and can't help beyond that. Feel free to start a question of your own

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to do a Group By on `Group` using `Average` as your aggregate. That will get you the following table.

```
Group    Average
A        113.3
B        213.3
```

Then you can merge this new table into your original one matching on `Group`, then expand the `Average` column.